# javascript - how many emails we can send in nodeJs by using NodeMailer at a time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, shared-hosting, nodemailer

I am working on an application which functionality is to sending continuous email using NodeJs and Angular. My problem is when I am sending more than 40 or 50 emails then, it is not delivering to recipient and I am also not getting any kind of error in console

```
 var emailArray = [hello1@gmail.com, hello1@gmail.com ....hello40@gmail.com];
 var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
    host: 'md-19.webhostbox.net',
    port: 465,
    ssl: true,
    auth: {
        user: 'info@abc.com',                  // bluehost
        pass: 'abc12345'
    }
}));
var message = {
    from: "Name <info@abc.com>",
    to: emailArray,
    subject: 'subject',
    html: '<b>Hello world</b>'
};
transporter.sendMail(message, function(error, info) {
         console.log(error || info);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The only limit, is the the max tcp connections you can handle.

Comment: Yes, i can handle tcp connections

Comment: I think this also depends on which service you're using to deliver the emails. "Gmail has a limit of 500 recipients a day (a message with one To and one Cc address counts as two messages since it has two recipients) for @gmail.com addresses" according to https://github.com/SparkPost/Nodemailer